# How to handle a before refresh the window with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

Im trying to handle the action of the user before refreshing the page using F5 or the refresh button or what ever so i can call a function that close some process.

Comment: `locationChangeStart` will not fire if the user hits F5 to refresh the page @Kaiido It sounds more like a case of `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: @Ronnie yeah thats it but i need something like that with angular

Comment: what exactly is happening that you need to execute in `onbeforeunload`? I'd generally stay away from that.

Comment: @Ronnie in my view im opening some process, so now if the user refresh the view, the process are still open in the server but not in the view so with a funciton i already got i can close them in the server SO what i want to do is to use this function when the user refresh the view so the process would be close

Comment: Ok, I gotcha. I cannot really think of another way of handling closing those processes. Can you close them server side? Like a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve that problem with Angular you can use the Event $locationChangeStart.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
     var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page");
     if (!answer) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }    
});
```